# Should Get or should Post be used to get AJAX content that expires often?

Tags: ajax, post, get

I have AJAX calls that get content that expires often.

To get that content is is better practice to use:

- Post

or

- Get and set the Cache Expiration Date as immediate on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GET` with this kind of header: `"Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"`
[read when `POST` should be used](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5).

Answer (score 0):

If you're only retrieving data, then you should use `GET` and use the appropriate cache-related HTTP headers.